# Fourier Transform of $\cos(\pi t)+2\sin(3\pi t)+\cos(5\pi t)\cos(7\pi t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I think I understand this question up until the last term. So far I have:

$$F(\omega)=\pi(\delta(\omega+\pi) + \delta(\omega-\pi))+2\pi(\delta(\omega+3\pi) + \delta(\omega-3\pi))+\frac{1}{2}(\delta(\omega+5\pi) + \delta(\omega-5\pi)*\delta(\omega+7\pi) + \delta(\omega-7\pi))$$

I don't understand how to convolve the delta functions. Let me know if I am on the right track with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convolve the delta functions, because

$$\cos{5 \pi t} \cos{7 \pi t} = \frac12 (\cos{2 \pi t} + \cos{12 \pi t})$$

Comment: would you car to explain which property you used to find this?

Comment: @user1971854: cosine addition theorem: $$\cos{(a+b)} = \cos{a} \cos{b} - \sin{a} \sin{b}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still missing the connection. Where does the sine term go, where does $cos(2\pi t)$ come from and why is it scaled by 1/2?

Comment: @user1971854: If you are talking about convolutions and delta functions, then you should be able to consider $\cos{(a-b)}$ and add them together to figure this out.

Comment: Aha, I see it now. Thank you for your help!